# Mirror the Android Tablet Browser to Windows Browser

Tags: browser, samsung-galaxy-tab

Is there any way I could mirror the default browser on Android 4.0+ to a web browser/emulator on my Windows PC? When I developed apps on native Android, there was a way through the IDE.

Can I accomplish this with the web browser also?